# Get all unique values from objects and assign them into array under correct key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, unique-key

I have an array of objects to be converted to an object with an array of unique values assigned to the same keys.

How can I get this output?

*//input*

```
let users = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alan", surname: "Davis", age: 34, isAdmin: 'yes'},
  { id: 2, name: "John", surname: "Doe", age: 35, isAdmin: 'no'},
  { id: 3, name: "Monica", surname: "Bush", age: 25, isAdmin: 'no'},
  { id: 4, name: "Sandra", surname: "Back", age: 23, isAdmin: 'no'},
  { id: 5, name: "Jacob", surname: "Front", age: 34, isAdmin: 'yes'},
];
```

*//output*

```
let unique = {
  id: [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5],
  name: ['Alan', 'John', 'Monica', 'Sandra', 'Jacob'],
  surname: ['Davis', 'Doe', 'Bush', 'Back', 'Front'],
  age: [34, 35, 25, 23],
  isAdmin: ['yes', 'no'],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and for all of the items iterate over with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and creating a unique array with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Code:

```js
const users = [{ id: 1, name: 'Alan', surname: 'Davis', age: 34, isAdmin: 'yes' },{ id: 2, name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', age: 35, isAdmin: 'no' },{ id: 3, name: 'Monica', surname: 'Bush', age: 25, isAdmin: 'no' },{ id: 4, name: 'Sandra', surname: 'Back', age: 23, isAdmin: 'no' },{ id: 5, name: 'Jacob', surname: 'Front', age: 34, isAdmin: 'yes' },]

const unique = users.reduce((a, c) => (
  Object
    .entries(c)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => a[k] = [...new Set([...(a[k] || []), v])]), 
  a
), {})

console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

1. Iterate over the keys of the first object in the array to produce a list of keys
2. Create an array of the corresponding values.  Filter the array for dupes.
3. Wrap the keys and values back into an object

```js
let users = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alan", surname: "Davis", age: 34, isAdmin: 'yes'},
  { id: 2, name: "John", surname: "Doe", age: 35, isAdmin: 'no'},
  { id: 3, name: "Monica", surname: "Bush", age: 25, isAdmin: 'no'},
  { id: 4, name: "Sandra", surname: "Back", age: 23, isAdmin: 'no'},
  { id: 5, name: "Jacob", surname: "Front", age: 34, isAdmin: 'yes'},
];

let unique = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(users[0]).map(k => 
    [k, users.map(u => u[k]).filter((value, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(value) === i)]
  )
);

console.log(unique);
```